# Using try-excepts in nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, exception, try-except

I have a nested loop where I perform a calculation over every grid-point in a 3-dimensional array. Some of these grid-points trigger an error. I want to calculate every possible grid-point and skip those that trigger the error.

I've tried:

```py
with sharedmem.MapReduce(np=45) as pool:
  def calc_func(abc):
    for k in range(241):
      try:
        for j in range(int(datetime_range)):
            for l in range((abc), abc+1):  
              value = calc(pr[j,k,l], te[j,k,l], de[j,k,l])
              array[j,k,l] = value
      except (IndexError, ValueError):
        continue
  pool.map(cape_func, range(0, 479))
```

^ Above, some grid-points are calculated, but I think when k values are caught in the exception, the code doesn't calculate the rest of the grid-points for that k.

Below, I tried adding another try-except block to iterate over all of the grid-points. I don't think this worked - it seems to be looping infinitely.

```py
with sharedmem.MapReduce(np=45) as pool:
  def calc_func(abc):
    for k in range(241):
      try:
        for j in range(int(datetime_range)):
          try:
             for l in range((abc), abc+1):  
               value = calc(pr[j,k,l], te[j,k,l], de[j,k,l])
               array[j,k,l] = value
          except (IndexError, ValueError):
            continue
      except (IndexError, ValueError):
        continue
  pool.map(cape_func, range(0, 479))
```

Comment: why dont you just put the try catch around the expressions in the third inner for loop?

Comment: I think you might be looking for a `pass` statement instead of a `continue`. But I might not have understood your questions well.

on the side note, can you not vectorise it?

Comment: It also looks like the only thing that could throw `Index` or `Value` errors is the `calc` function, since all your loop are over a ranges. Why don't you just wrap the 2 code lines with the function and array assignment?

Comment: Yes, probably you need `pass`, because i think that `continue` exit from the for loop.

Comment: Thanks @JuliaBogutskaya, that was probably the best solution. I'm not sure why I didn't do that before, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. There's still something fundamentally wrong but I think the try-except is working. I'll have to investigate this further.

Comment: @Amethyst, great! Glad I could help. I have posted it as an answer. Could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a `pass` statement instead of a `continue`. But I might not have understood your questions well. On the side note, can you not vectorise it?

It also looks like the only thing that could throw `Index` or `Value` errors is the `calc` function, since all your loop are over a ranges. Why don't you just wrap the 2 code lines with the function and array assignment?